# How to pass a value to a struct function from outside?

Tags: c++, struct, static, parameter-passing

There is a `struct`  defined in my code for which I would like to pass a value from 'outside'. Here is an example for this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   struct st
   {
      static void print(int a, int b)
      {
         string swtch = "+";
         if (swtch == "+")
         {
            cout << a + b << endl;
         }
         else if (swtch == "-")
         {
            cout << a - b << endl;
         }
         else
         {
            cout << 
               "Warning: This case is not implemented." << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
         }
      }
   };
   st::print(1,2);
   return 0;
}
```

It would be useful to move the statement `string swtch = "+";` outside the struct `st` (e.g., right after `int main(){`somehow. Could you please give advice how to then pass `swtch` to `st::print()`?

Comment: Why not pass as additional parameter? Wouldn't be a simple `char` enough (instead of the far more complex `std::string`)?

Comment: General advice: `system("pause");` is rather bad idea inside console programmes. It is not the task of an application to keep some console window open, in worst case, this prevents the application to be run from inside some script. Instead, you might open the console explicitly and run your programme from within.

Comment: You don't need "a struct" for this, it is just a distraction.

Comment: This is only an example, the real task is different from that presented in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  struct st {
    static void print(int a, int b, string swtch) {
      if (swtch == "+") {
        cout << a + b << endl;
      } else if (swtch == "-") {
        cout << a - b << endl;
      } else {
        cout << "Warning: This case is not implemented." << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
      }
    }
  };
  st::print(1, 2, "+");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 struct st
 {
  static void print(int a, int b,char swtch)
  {
     if (swtch == '+')
     {
        cout << a + b << endl;
     }
     else if (swtch == '-')
     {
        cout << a - b << endl;
     }
     else
     {
        cout << 
           "Warning: This case is not implemented." << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
     }
  }
 };
char c ;
cin>>c;
st::print(1,2,c);
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to OOP your `st`, something like:

```
class st
{
private:
    std::string swtch;

public:
    st(const std::string st)
    {
        swtch = st;
    }

    void print(int a, int b)
    {
       if (swtch == "+")
       {
          cout << a + b << endl;
       }
       else if (swtch == "-")
       {
          cout << a - b << endl;
       }
       else
       {
          cout << "Warning: This case is not implemented." << endl;
          system("pause");
          exit(0);
       }
    }
}

int main()
{
    st my_st("+");
    my_st.print(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```